# Office carpet tiles / Remove trim and do vinyl trim?

Tags: flooring, carpet

I have 3400 Sq ft of mostly offices, and the space is trimmed out with residential composite painted baseboard .   The floors were carpeted with broadcloth carpet and tack strips.

We want to put in new carpet tiles and have to jack up a bunch of office furniture to do so.

I don't have experience with commercial carpet tiles.   Should we plan on pulling the baseboard and doing vinyl trim around the perimeters?

Could the base be saved? I've seen tons of residential tack strip carpet pulled to the base, not sure on commercial / carpet tiles.

[image]

Comment: If you like the trim now, just carefully remove it and then put back.  A tip will be to add a number on the piece and the wall behind the trim.

Comment: Honestly I'm kind of indifferent, if we have to pull it off,  vinyl trim is way less work.  The labor to pull the baseboard, tack it back up, caulk, and repaint is not nothing.   It's a lot of linear feet.   There's like 12 offices of cuts and craziness

Comment: That is why you mark the pieces so they go back the right way.  Trim is a personal choice so you can do what is best for you.

Comment: @Leroy105, You have answered your own question. If you do not like the cost of removing and reinstalling the current trim and prefer the vinyl because of less work...well there is your answer.